# Why adapter always change images position?

Tags: java, android

i have 6 ImageView's in GridView and i need to set images what gets from array of drawables to image views, i'm using BaseAdapter, before first scrolling all good.
Here is image view implementing,

```
     ArrayList<ImageView> images;
             images = new ArrayList<>();

             holder.ph1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph1);
             images.add(holder.ph1);
             holder.ph2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph2);
             images.add(holder.ph2);
             holder.ph3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph3);
             images.add(holder.ph3);
             holder.ph4 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph4);
             images.add(holder.ph4);
             holder.ph5 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph5);
             images.add(holder.ph5);
             holder.ph6 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph6);
             images.add(holder.ph6);
```

Here is set images fragment of code

```
List<String> items = Arrays.asList(Helicopters.data.get(position).get("images").toString().split("\\s*,\\s*"));
         Collections.sort(items);
         for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
         {
             resID1 = MainActivity.act.getResources().getIdentifier("dop_" + (Integer.parseInt(items.get(i))), "drawable", MainActivity.act.getPackageName());
             images.get(Integer.parseInt(items.get(i))-1).setImageResource(resID1);
         }
```

---

All BaseAdapter code and screenshot of images, **trouble goes on when im scrolling, all images change position**...

```
public class HeliAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    int resID,resID1;
    ArrayList<ImageView> images;

    static class HistoryHolder
     {
         TextView name;
         TextView art;
         ImageView ph1,ph2,ph3,ph4,ph5,ph6;
         SketchImageView photo;
     }

     public HeliAdapter(Context context) {
         mContext = context;
     }

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
         return Helicopters.data.size();
     }

     @Override
     public Object getItem(int position) {
         return Helicopters.data.size();
     }

     @Override
     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         final HistoryHolder holder;

         if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                     .inflate(R.layout.toy_item, null);

             holder = new HistoryHolder();
             holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
             holder.art = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.art);


             holder.photo = (SketchImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

             ArrayList<ImageView> images;
             images = new ArrayList<>();

             holder.ph1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph1);
             images.add(holder.ph1);
             holder.ph2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph2);
             images.add(holder.ph2);
             holder.ph3 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph3);
             images.add(holder.ph3);
             holder.ph4 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph4);
             images.add(holder.ph4);
             holder.ph5 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph5);
             images.add(holder.ph5);
             holder.ph6 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ph6);
             images.add(holder.ph6);


             convertView.setTag(holder);
         } else {
             holder = (HistoryHolder) convertView.getTag();
         }

         String mDrawableName = "a_" + Helicopters.number(Helicopters.data.get(position).get("#").toString()) + "_1";
         resID = MainActivity.act.getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName, "drawable", MainActivity.act.getPackageName());

         holder.photo.displayResourceImage(MainActivity.act.getResources().getIdentifier("a_"+Helicopters.data.get(position).get("#").toString()+"_1" , "drawable", MainActivity.act.getPackageName()));

         List<String> items = Arrays.asList(Helicopters.data.get(position).get("Иконки").toString().split("\\s*,\\s*"));
         Collections.sort(items);
    //   Log.e("Cars", items.toString());
         for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
         {
//           Log.e("orig", (Integer.parseInt(items.get(i)))+"");
//           Log.e("parse", (Integer.parseInt(items.get(i))-1)+"");
//      //   Log.e("original", (Integer.parseInt(items.get(i))-1)+"");
             resID1 = MainActivity.act.getResources().getIdentifier("dop_" + (Integer.parseInt(items.get(i))), "drawable", MainActivity.act.getPackageName());
             images.get(Integer.parseInt(items.get(i))-1).setImageResource(resID1);
         }
         holder.name.setText(Helicopters.data.get(position).get("Название").toString());
         holder.art.setText("Арт. " + Helicopters.data.get(position).get("#").toString());


         return convertView;
     }

 }
```

**Before scrolling**
[image]

**After scrolling**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please make your position value to final

```
 @Override
     public View getView(final int position
................
.....
```

Comment: give me 2 minutes

Comment: without changes :c